# Community rejected that edit even though it is correcting obvious mistakes

Tags: discussion, editing

I improved the following [very detailed answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/147243/how-to-get-result-3-otimes-3-6-oplus-bar3-for-su3-irreducible-repre/187561#187561) in which a vector (column) is wrongly written as a 3 by 3 matrix and which has internal links to some equations that don't work in math stackexchange (one sees (???)), and that I put by hand. Why is this rejected, did someone even check that the corrections were true?

I also did other minor changes. Here is the ["edit rejected"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/86049) page

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "edit rejected" page actually tells you:

> *"This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit."*

meaning that the post has been edited (in this case by its owner) since you submitted the edit. If a post is edited, all other suggested edits for it are automatically discarded.